# Как сделать, чтобы элементы словаря записывались в файл по уменьшению значения?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
tags = dict()
def val_return(key):
    return tags[key]
with open('tweets.txt') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        line = line.split()
        for word in line:
            if word[0] == '#' and word not in tags:
                tags[word] = 1
            if word in tags:
                tags[word] += 1
with open('tags.txt', 'a', encoding = 'UTF-8') as file1:
    for key in tags:
        file1.write(f'тег: {key}, упоминаний: {tags[key]}\n')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должна быть сортировка по ключу и по значению(сначала идет большее, затем меньшее)

Comment: Предлаю решение с большого SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/613218/13435478

Comment: @Стас спасибо. помогло